# "rails new [Blah]" No such file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

So I'm new to Ruby and also to Rails. I have recently installed Ruby on Arch Linux.
It was mostly all fine any happy except for a few errors here and there but now when I try initializing a new rails app using `rails new AppName` I get the error

```
bash: /home/[username]/.gem/ruby/2.3.0/bin/rails: No such file or directory
```

I've tried creating a file and directory called `rails` in but get more errors.

reinstalling rails same outcome

reinstalling ruby same outcome

following any other dependencies at install also leads no wear.

Ask for any info you may need.
Thanks in advance

UPDATE
installing of gems is now stopped by a common error

```
$ gem install rails
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Errno::EACCES)
Permission denied @ rb_sysopen - /usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.3.0/nokogiri-1.6.8/gem_make.out
```

and the same when I try install `nokogiri`

Comment: could you provide the output of `gem install rails --no-ri --no-rdoc` command please?

Comment: What steps did you perform to install Ruby and Rails?

Comment: to install ruby on rails
`sudo pacman -S ruby`
`gem install rails`

Comment: $ gem install rails --no-ri --no-rdoc
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Errno::EACCES)
    Permission denied @ rb_sysopen - /usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.3.0/nokogiri-1.6.8/gem_make.out

$ sudo gem install rails --no-ri --no-rdoc
Ignoring byebug-9.0.5 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine byebug --version 9.0.5
WARNING:  You don't have /root/.gem/ruby/2.3.0/bin in your PATH,
          gem executables will not run.
Successfully installed rails-5.0.0
1 gem installed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The overall problem is a lack of permissions to `/usr/lib/ruby/`. This can be fixed with

```
sudo chmod 777 /usr/lib/ruby
```

Answer (score 1):

ok first check that you installed both ruby and rails well

```
ruby -v
```

and

```
rails -v
```

so if you get a respond to that you're all good 
go to the place you want to create your folder att

```
rails new appname
```

then

```
cd appname
```

if that doesn't work try to generate anything

```
rails generate controller appname
```

if the generate works then your rails is ok if not then you might want to add the rails to your environment variable path.
You installed ruby on your computer. However the path is not recognized yet on it. To add it  you can do this . if you are using windows my computer right click and then chose advanced system settings -> advanced at the bottom environment variables system variables PATH and then add the the path to your ruby bin folder. I am sorry i don't have enough reputation so can't add pictures but reading this will solve your problem

Comment: I am guessing it's adding rails to environment variables so steps are as follows if you are using windows my computer right click and then chose advanced system settings -> advanced at the bottom environment variables system variables PATH and then add the the path to your ruby bin folder. 
I am sorry i don't have enough reputation so can't add pictures but reading this will solve your problem

Comment: oh. ok so `rails` on its own gives `bash: /home/[username]/.gem/ruby/2.3.0/bin/rails: No such file or directory`.
Then i reset my console it `rails` now gives me `bash: /home/[username]/.gem/ruby/2.3.0/bin/rails: No such file or directory`
This suggests that whatever im doing to install rails is not placing it in my PATH(yes i have PATH pointed at `~/.gem/ruby/2.3.0/bin`
So what am i doing wrong in my installation of the gem?

Comment: Ya its adding your ruby to the environment variables path. So the system would find it. Go to ruby bin and copy the path and add it as i edited in my answer. Hope that helps.

Comment: So if this is the right answer can you mark it as right answer? Or if you are still having a problem we can see whats wrong. Thanks